# React landing page shows different color and missing images on mobile. Despite looking perfect on dev and on google chrome dev tools mobile

Tags: reactjs, vite, netlify

I started using react and as an excerise i made a simple buisness landing page ( i know react is an overkill for this ) i deployed the page to netlify. On desktop everything looks great, but from my phone (Iphone 11 ) the main color is green instead of blue. And the backgroud image of divs of the info section are not showing at all. Despite working in dev tools. I tried moving the images to the public folder and still the same.
this is the website
https://656c87d21d7bce08094ba7b8--serene-semifreddo-9aea23.netlify.app/

i tried deploying it on github pages and the same problem is ocurring.
( also the webiste loads so slow, but i havent figured out why yet)
any help is appreciated. im just starting.

I tried moving the assest/images to the public folder but still the same. I also tried changing the CSS for mobile but still doesnt show in prod. but in dev does